# res.send() gives HTML code instead of rendering it

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express 4 with Node JS, below is my code:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/socket', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('<p>Hello</p>');
});
```

But it shows the following

[image]

instead of rending the p tag, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe, You are not telling browser, that you are sending HTML data, not text file

Comment: @Lixas How would I do that?

Comment: I tried   res.type('.html') &   res.type('html') with no different result

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
res.setHeader('Content-type','text/html')
```

set the header before sending response.

Answer (score 2):

`res.send().` **Sends a string response in a format**
Try this

```
> res.write('<h1>Hello, World!</h1>');
```

`res.send` can only be called once in a code, but it is same as `res.write` + `res.end()`

Answer (score -2):

To get h1 header in output, you can use the following code
here i have used 3 const to demonstrate their use with it

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/socket', (req, res, next) => {
    const city="Londan";
    const country="England";
    const temp=24;
    res.send("<h1>Hello, The temperature in "+city+","+country+" is "+temp+"</h1>");
});
```

use " nodemon app.js "  to run server
" ctrl + c "  to end a server.

Comment: You doing the same as a question is asked.

Comment: It will not render HTML content , it will give output